# How to solve the following expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following expression: $2^{n-3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}(n-k+1)^2$ and I have no idea how to solve it. I tried plugging it in WolframAlpha to get an idea but it gives me $-n^2 - 4 n + 7 \cdot 2^{n - 1} - 6$ and I have even less of an idea how I would get there.

I don't need the complete solution done. I just would like pointers on how to solve it.

Comment: If you know how to compute $\sum_k 2^k k^2$ and $\sum_k 2^k k$, you have done

Comment: What do yo man by "solve" ? Get a closed form (= compact) expression ? Keep the word "solve" for equations or to expressions like "I want to solve the following problem..."

Comment: I know a method but it a long method. You actually write down the summation as a series. That is, $2^{n-3} + 2^0.(n)^2+2^1.(n-1)^2 + \cdots 2^{n-4}.(n-n-2)^2$. Then you expand out the square and common out the $n^2$ terms where you get a geometric progression. When you common out the $-n$ term, you get an arithmetico-geometric series.And the rest are just sum of sqares.

Answer (score 0):

Expand:
$$E=2^{n-3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}(n-(k-1))^2=\\
2^{n-3}+\color{red}{n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}}-2n\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}(k-1)2^{k-1}}+\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}(k-1)^22^{k-1}}$$
One:
$$\color{red}{n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}}=n^2\cdot \frac{2^{n-3}-1}{2-1}=\color{red}{n^2\cdot 2^{n-3}-n^2}$$
Two:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} x^{k-1}=\frac{x^{n-3}-1}{x-1}\\
f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)x^{k-2}=\frac{(n-3)x^{n-4}(x-1)-x^{n-3}+1}{(x-1)^2}\\
xf'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)x^{k-1}=\frac{(n-4)x^{n-2}-(n-3)x^{n-3}+x}{(x-1)^2}\\
2f'(2)=\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)2^{k-1}}=(n-4)2^{n-2}-(n-3)2^{n-3}+2=\\
\color{green}{n\cdot 2^{n-3}-5\cdot 2^{n-3}+2}$$
Three:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)x^{k-1}=\frac{(n-4)x^{n-2}-(n-3)x^{n-3}+x}{(x-1)^2}\\
f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)^2x^{k-2}=\cdots\\
xf'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)^2x^{k-1}=\cdots\\
2f'(2)=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k-1)^22^{k-1}}=\cdots=\\
\color{blue}{n^2\cdot 2^{n-3}-5n\cdot 2^{n-2}+27\cdot 2^{n-3}-6}$$
If all plugged in, it results in the stated answer.

Wolfram [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D%2Bn%5E2%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D-n%5E2-2n%28n%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D-5%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D%2B2%29%2Bn%5E2%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D-5n%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-2%7D%2B27%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-3%7D-6).

Answer (score 0):

You'll just to simplify the expression

$f(n) = 2^{n-3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}*(n-k+1)^2$

Now let's expand

$f(n) = 2^{n-3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}*(n^2-2*k*n+2*n+k^2-2*k+1)$

Let's reduce it

$f(n) = 2^{n-3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}*(n^2+2*n+1) +\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}*(-2*k*n-2*k) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1}*(k^2)$

Simplify more

$f(n) = 2^{n-3}+ (n^2+2*n+1)*\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1} -2*(n+1)*\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} k*2^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k^2)*2^{k-1}$

Remember that 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} 2^{k-1} = 1+2+2^2+2^3+...........+2^{n-3-1} = 2^{n-3}-1$

It's becomes difficult here

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} k*2^{k-1} = h(x) = k*2^{k-1}+(k-1)*2^{k-2}+(k-2)*2^{k-3}+........+3*2^2+2*2^1+1*2^0$

But It's not so hard to see that 
$h(x)*2-k*2^k = 2*h(x-1)$

You'll need to solve some recurring equation now

$h(x) = 2^x*(x-1)+1$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} (k^2)*2^{k-1} = g(x) = (k^2)*2^{k-1}+(k-1)^2*2^{k-2}+(k-2)^2*2^{k-3}+........+ 3^2*2^2+2^2*2+1$

Same process involved we can also see that
$g(x)*2 -x^2*2^x = 2*g(x-1)$

So that $g(x) = 2^x*(x^2-2*x+3)-3$

Don't forget that the plugin value is $h(n-3)$ and $g(n-3)$

Therefore
$f(n) = 2^{n-3}+(n^2+2*n+1)*(2^{n-3}-1)-2*(n+1)*(2^{n-3}*(n-3-1)+1)+2^{n-3}*((n-3)^2-2*(n-3)+3)-3$

Expand and simplify this to get our solution

$f(n) = 7*2^{n-1}-n^2-4*n-6$

So you see that the trick is recurring equation, which Wolfram automatically solves